# How do I pass an ExpandoObject from C# into IronRuby?

Tags: dynamic, c#-4.0, ironruby, expandoobject

Executing the below code gives me the following exception on the last line:

**InvalidOperationException: "unbound variable: value"**

```
var rubyRuntime = Ruby.CreateRuntime();
rubyRuntime.UseFile("HandleMoveRequested.rb");
var engine = rubyRuntime.GetEngine("rb");
dynamic ruby = engine.Runtime.Globals;

var handler = ruby.HandleMoveRequested.@new();

dynamic msg = new ExpandoObject();
msg.x = 1;
msg.y = 2;

handler.handle(msg);
```

The contents of HandleMoveRequested.rb are:

```
class HandleMoveRequested
    def handle(msg)
        System::Console.WriteLine msg.x
        System::Console.WriteLine msg.y
    end
end
```

Basically I just want to be able to pass a fully dynamic object into that Ruby object's "handle" method and have it be able to access the "x" and "y" properties on that object. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code (as-is) after building the latest from source:
http://github.com/ironruby/ironruby

Please try this. I'd imagine the fix will be included in the next RC Build (RC3?) and later.
When you build from source, **make sure you build the "V4 Release" build using Ruby4.sln**

**Edit:** Tested myself, this works without issue in latest